# Okta as IDP and simplesamlphp as SP - IDP initiated login does not work

Tags: single-sign-on, okta, simplesamlphp

so I am able to make the SP initiated login work using simplesamlphp but there does not seem to be a way to make it work when clicking on the Okta Chicklet.

Here are the logs I am presented with when trying to login:

Feb  7 10:21:25 simplesamlphp[22997]: 7 [e5966815bb] Has 1 candidate keys for validation.

Feb  7 10:21:25 simplesamlphp[22997]: 7 [e5966815bb] Validation with key #0 succeeded.

Feb  7 10:21:25 simplesamlphp[22997]: 7 [e5966815bb] Has 1 candidate keys for validation.

Feb  7 10:21:25 simplesamlphp[22997]: 7 [e5966815bb] Validation with key #0 succeeded.

Feb  7 10:21:25 simplesamlphp[22997]: 7 [e5966815bb] Filter config for http://www.okta.com/**my_id**->**my_domain**/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/test: array (  0 =>   sspmod_core_Auth_Process_LanguageAdaptor::__set_state(array(     'langattr' => 'preferredLanguage',     'priority' => 90,  )),)

Feb  7 10:21:25 simplesamlphp[22997]: 7 [e5966815bb] Session: doLogin("test")

Feb  7 10:21:25 simplesamlphp[22997]: 7 [e5966815bb] Session: doLogout('test')

Feb  7 10:21:25 simplesamlphp[22997]: 7 [e5966815bb] Session: 'test' not valid because we are not authenticated.

Comment: Then I proceed to see a saml response from okta - the same i see when I do when I do SP initiated login.

Only when I do SP initiated login I finally see this after the okta response:
Session: Valid session found with 'test'

I see that log two times then

Comment: IdP initiated login to an SSP SP work fine for us. Why is your SP calling 'doLogout' and clearing the session? Do you have default relay state defined in your authsources.php or in the Okta app?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a `RelayState` for the Okta SP in `authsources.php`? I had an issue connecting simplesamlphp and Okta that was generating the same log entries and that fixed it.